# Как получить результаты SQL запроса?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Использую Codeigniter.
Добавляю строку в БД следующим запросом:

```
function add_transaction($data) 
{
    $this->db->insert("transactions", $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Как получить ID строки, которая была добавлена в БД?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942216/this-db-insert-id-not-working-in-mysql-codeigniter

Comment: а Вы что получаете?